# Separating two divs

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a page, at the top of which there is a button (aligned to the right), followed by the main page content in a div.

I've encountered an issue when trying to separate the button and the main content div. The two divs are currently overlapping. I don't imagine this to be a huge issue, but I'd like to clarify what the most accepted way of separating these would be, rather than just messing about with margins etc.

```css
.view-all-container {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.view-all {
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}


.main-section {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-all-container">
  <a class="view-all">View our range of holiday homes</a>
</div>

<div class="main-section">
  
</div>
```

I've found that when I add a `margin-top: 50px` to `.main-section` the button travels with it, as if it's contained within the same div.

Comment: Are you actually trying to offset the button div or just align it to the right of the parent?

Comment: @carledwards sorry, should have linked to the rough example of how I wanted it: [image](https://ibb.co/nC8xVR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for best practices then consider the following:

1) Avoid using `float`. There are many better ways to get elements where you want them without needing to revert to a complicated process. The biggest problem with `float` is that it removes your element from the normal DOM flow.  https://designshack.net/articles/css/farewell-floats-the-future-of-css-layout/, https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/07/the-secret-to-designing-website-layouts-without-css-floats/

2) If you are navigating, then use the `<a>` tag. If you are doing something on the same page use a `<button>` or `<input type='button'/>` https://davidwalsh.name/html5-buttons

Here is a simple fix for what you want:

```css
.view-all-container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.view-all {
  background-color: #808080;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: middle;
}


.main-section {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-all-container">
  <button class="view-all">View our range of holiday homes</button>
</div>

<div class="main-section">
  Stuff in the main section
</div>
```

I removed the `float` and changed to `text-align`. The `<div>` is already `display: block` so I removed that.

I assumed that your button at the top was to make changes on the active page so I changed the html from an `<a>` tag to a `<button>`.

---

If you don't want to use `text-align` then try `flex-box`:

```css
.view-all-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.view-all {
  background-color: #808080;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}


.main-section {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-all-container">
  <button class="view-all">View our range of holiday homes</button>
</div>

<div class="main-section">
  Stuff in the main section
</div>
```

One of my favorite quotes about using `float` comes from this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/

> If you’re new to CSS layouts, you’d be forgiven for thinking that using CSS floats in imaginative ways is the height of skill. If you have consumed as many CSS layout tutorials as you can find, you might suppose that mastering floats is a rite of passage. You’ll be dazzled by the ingenuity, astounded by the complexity, and you’ll gain a sense of achievement when you finally understand how floats work.
>
> Don’t be fooled. You’re being brainwashed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the very detailed answer. That helps a lot!

Comment: That's poor advice to ignore using floats. There's nothing wrong at all in using them. It's when people use them without knowing what they do or how they work that causes problems.

Comment: I second @j08691 sentiments and also the fact that you're essentially aligning **all**  text right in that container when the original attention was just to align the button itself.

Comment: I fixed the `text-align`. But floats were a hack. `clearFix` is a hack. Almost every article that talks about `clearfix` admits it is a hack. `flex-box` is probably the best way to do it. Using `display: flow-root` is even better: https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/01/24/the-end-of-the-clearfix-hack/

Comment: @intervalia thanks for the update. I'm not new to CSS - I've been a front-end dev for 4ish years. But I learned using tutorials on Codecademy, where `floats` were taught primarily. Interesting to learn about the other methods.

Comment: To be honest I will *sparingly* use a `float` but it has to be something special to need it. I think I used it twice in the last year. The problem about most technology is that someone writes a great article and then dozens more write similar articles because it is all they know. But having lots of articles not not mean that tech is the best thing to use. `grid` mode is great too, but not available on older browsers, so I tend to use `flex` for most things and I will even go back to `text-align` when dealing with only a few sub-elements. Find the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear the float with `clear:right` on `.main-section`

```css
.view-all-container {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.view-all {
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-section {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-all-container">
  <a class="view-all">View our range of holiday homes</a>
</div>

<div class="main-section">

</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot - I knew there'd be a simple way to do it.